# Can we have the facility to cancel flags that have been overtaken by events?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467933/managing-all-cron-jobs-through-a-single-file) was asked today. It's not a great question and probably deserves to be closed as opinion-based or too broad. The real problem here was the comments.

I flagged this question at 28 comments (there are only 15 as I type this), when the subject matter had strayed too far from the point, a small bout of name-calling had occurred, and nothing constructive was being achieved.

A few minutes later I see that the dross has been removed, but now I have a 'pending' flag outstanding. Clearly a moderator has spotted the mess and tidied it up, but my flag remains for some long suffering mod to handle sometime in the next few days.

I'd like to just cancel my flag, but I can find no way to do it. This is just one example, but there are others (NAA edited to something useful after flagging, for example)

So please - can I cancel my flags?

Comment: Your scenario appears to involve a moderator reacting to the flag but neglecting to actually dismiss it. This should be fairly rare.

Comment: @Shog9 Perhaps in this case, but there have been other occasions where I've flagged something only for it to be OBE. The resulting flag has subsequently been declined or disputed. It's not a huge problem, but I've frequently seen comments from mods on the sheer volume of flags they deal with daily - it would just be nice to clear the redundant flag and save the mods their time.